# mysql query in php not returning a value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

EDIT::

The current code being used is :

```
  //$username= 'lmfsthefounder';
  $type = "SELECT account_type from user_attribs WHERE username='lmfsthefounder';";
  $type_again = mysql_query($type);
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($type_again);
  $usertype = $row['account_type'];
  echo $usertype;
```

which returns like this: Home Login Register Usertype is

When I search this query in mysql query explorer, it shows me the value is 1. I need that 1 to echo in my page.

(This should display 'Usertype is 1' in my navigation bar)

Comment: `mysql_query` is a dead function, soon to be removed from the language. Try PDO.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql function you are looking for is `mysql_fetch_assoc` ([link](http://nz1.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)) instead of `mysql_fetch_row`.

But please, PLEASE don't use mysql_ functions. The link to the PHP manual tells you the same.

I would recommend trying to teach yourself [how to use the mySQL PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). There are many great tutorials online.

Comment: I am going to work on that, but I am using an old version of php on my server, so at the moment its safe. I will be converting over to newer code very shortly.